# Problem with compiz profiles

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gconf

I've been struggling with this problem for the last few days. In Oneiric compiz and unity don't get along very well and on top of that I think there's some problem with the compiz-gconf communication . Here's what's happening - I've had various bugs with defaulting options and profiles (compiz and system settings - for ex. the launch terminal shortcut defaulted 2-3 times) . Last thing that happened - I configured compiz to use flat-file backend (no gconf) , it worked but on restart the edge-bindings (expo,windows scale) weren't working (the expo only opened with binding and didn't close ,so I figured the launcher could be the problem) . As I feel I'm just rambling lets get to the most persistent bug :
 When GConf backend is enabled in ccsm->preferences it shows the profiles "Default" and two more with names of invalid characters . The last two appeared after I imported my profile (two times), I tried to erase them but with no success . I erased one of the profiles from the gconf (compizconfig) folder , but it still showed in ccsm .
 That's all that I can think of for now , I hope the thread's editable.

PS: the directories in .gconf/ are compiz-1 and configcompiz-1 , why the "-1"s ?

Comment: I experience the same, and have no luck in solving it. Even reinstalling unity and compiz didn't help it. It did fix default settings, so unity icons apeared. But all those weird characters in profile names are still here. Hope someone has solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two bugs about this that you might want to follow:

http://pad.lv/875400 - Unity shell doesn't fully load after crash in compiz settings manager
http://pad.lv/874799 - Broken list of profiles is given by compizconfig-backend-gconf